# Canvas element 'rubbing out' effect with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, html5-canvas, drawable

I have a canvas `<canvas></canvas>` that displays a graphic of an unclean window.  I need to be able to 'clean' the window with my cursor, displaying another image behind it.  Just as this website uses their brushes: http://mudcu.be/sketchpad/ but rather than adding to the page, I need to remove content to display the image behind it.

Here's an **example** of the before and after 'rubbing out':

http://www.titaniumwebdesigns.com/images/forums/before.png       http://www.titaniumwebdesigns.com/images/forums/after.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this [**complete DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/8h9HX/8/)

`globalCompositeOperation` is one of the most nice features in canvas api.

To achieve the desired effect, I use `multiple canvas layers` and `globalCompositeOperation`.

In this solution we have 3 layers:

**Layer 1 - bottom**                                **Layer 2 - middle**
[image: bottom layer]       [image: middle layer]

**Layer 3 - top**
[image: top layer]

Middle and Top layers are static and only the middle layer is dynamically cleared using `globalCompositeOperation`.

```
middleCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";
```

With `globalCompositeOperation = "xor"`, the brush is drawn over the layer and clears the portion of canvas where it was drawn.

The final result is:
[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

To verify if the window is fully cleaned I create a hidden canvas with the same size of the others layers and drawn a black rectangle on it. When dragging the mouse over the canvas the layer 2 (middle) is cleared with a circle with transparent gradient color and now we also draw over the hidden canvas a circle with white color (might be any color different of black).

So on, we just verify the pixels of the hidden canvas and if there is no black pixels, the window is cleaned.

To get the image data we need to use something like:

```
imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, width, height)
```

and then get the pixels from the image data:

```
pixels = imageData.data;
```

The `requestAnimationFrame` routine is used for performance reason, because `getImageData` might be slow. The major change in the code is put the brush action inside an animation frame when dragging the mouse instead of do that action in each mouse move event. This allows the processor to have more time to do the pixel data verification.

Here is the modified fiddle with pixel data verification and an alert when the window is cleaned:
 [**jsFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/xQpdN/)

Comment: Great answer - is there some sort of callback function that can be put in place when the window has been completely cleared?

Comment: @Titanium : Yes! It's a bit hard because of pixel manipulation but I done it and updated the answer. (Might be other ways, this is just mine). Hope it's help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a canvas where you have drawn a blurred image into it once, you should be able to create that effect by creating a "brush" image (an image containing a semi-transparent circle, with soft edges), and then draw that image in the canvas at the mouse coordinate using:

```
canvasContext.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html

As soon as you have drawn the blurred image to the canvas, you just need to call the line above once and all drawn images after will use the specified composite operation.

Comment: Okay, great - that makes sense. Could you provide an example? I'm currently in the process of writing my own example: http://jsfiddle.net/pzg5G/1/

Comment: Great example, I wouldn't say it's dirty! Thanks again.